# easy_localization await till saved locale is loaded

Tags: flutter, localization

I am using [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) for translations in my Flutter app. Most of the parts are implemented and I am stuck with one last bit... My first screen is language selection which works fine for first-time app open. When the user opens the app for the second time I have to check whether the language is already selected or not, if not show the language selection screen, else take the user to the home screen.

```
runApp(EasyLocalization(
  child: MyApp(),
  supportedLocales: [Locale('en'), Locale('hi')],
  path: 'assets/translations',
  fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
  // startLocale: Locale('hi'),
  saveLocale: true,
));


print(context.locale.toString()); <--- this is null
if (context.locale == null) {
  // show language selection screen
} else {
  // send user to home screen
}
```

Steps that happens:

```
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Localization initialized
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Start
I/flutter ( 5466): open_app
I/flutter ( 5466): null <--- this is null
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init state
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [INFO] Saved locale loaded hi <--- this is what I want to wait for
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Build
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init Localization Delegate
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init provider
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Load Localization Delegate
I/flutter ( 5466): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Load asset from assets/translations
```

So I want to wait till the saved locale is loaded and then I can make the decision. Any suggestions on this?